# How to allow slashes in this PHP regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have been trying for hours now and also read the Regex wiki here on Stackoverflow but can't seem to accomplish this regex. This is the string I have:

`Lorem: 8 FB / Ipsum-/Dolor: Some Text / Dolor: Some text with (brackets) / Sit amet.: Some Text with/slash / foobar / Last one: 36 foos`

What I would like to extract is: `Lorem`, `Ipsum-/Dolor`, `Dolor`, `Sit amet.`, `Last one`. So basically everything from the beginning of the sentence or after a slash until the colon.

Whatever I try the problem is always the `foobar` since it always sticks together with `Last one`. What I tried for example so far is: `( \/ |\A)([^(?!.* \/ )].*?):` which I hoped would extract everything starting from a slash going until a colon but not if there is `/` (empty space, slash, empty space). That way I wanted to make sure not to get `foobar / Last one` returned.

Could someone provide me with some hint

Comment: Your logic is not clear to me. `Ipsum-/Dolor` is not after a dash and not at the beginning of a sentence. Maybe you can use clearer words?

Comment: Your explanation of the rules is not consistent or accurate. First you say "everything after a dash", then you say "everything starting from a slash." A dash is "-", a slash is either "\" or "/" (backwards or forwards slash). But even if you were consistent with that, your claim of what's extracted is also not consistent.

Comment: Right, sorry I got confused with slash and dash... I meant slash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that you make a common mistake placing a *sequence* of patterns into a character class (`[...]`) thus making the regex engine match a *single character* from the defined set. `[^(?!.* \/ )]` matches a single character other than `(`, `?`, `!`, `.`, etc.

You may use a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970):

```
(?: \/ |\A)((?:(?! \/ )[^:])+):
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FZOrA5/1). The literal spaces may be replaced with `\s` (if you can match any whitespaces) or `\h` (to only match horizontal whitespaces).

**Details**:

- `(?: \/ |\A)` - either space + `/` + space or start of string
- `((?:(?! \/ )[^:])+)` - Group 1 capturing one or more symbols other than `:` (`[^:]`) that is not a starting point for a *space* + `/` + *space* sequence
- `:` - a literal colon.